# restic - can't create backup from remote server

Tags: backup, restic

I want to backup a directory **FROM** `root@1.1.1.1:/home/user/mc` **TO** `/local/backup-folder` on my PC.

Why does this not work?

```
restic init --repo /local/backup-folder

restic -r /local/backup-folder backup sftp:root@1.1.1.1:/home/user/mc
sftp:root@1.1.1.1:/home/user/mc does not exist, skipping
init does not exist, skipping
Fatal: all target directories/files do not exist
```

Using `ssh root@1.1.1.1 ls /home/user/mc` works, and the remote directory does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `restic` backup tool can only back up files and directories from the local machine to a backup repository that may be local or remote.  You can not use `restic` to backup remote files.

There is an issue in the `restic` Github repository about exactly this, titled [Being able to backup files from SFTP to a repository](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/4030).  The issue is closed as a duplicate of an older issue titled [Allow "pulling" backups from remote servers](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/299).  The older issue is still open but has not seen much action since 2022.  My gut feeling is that such a feature won't get implemented very soon.

The general approach I would take is to run `restic` from the remote machine containing the data you want to back up, writing to the local `backup-folder` repository you just created.  If that is not feasible, consider possibly using `rsync -a --delete` to mirror the data to your local machine before backing it up (this would duplicate the data locally, and the backup would be of the local copy).

You could also try using `SSHFS` or mounting the data in some other way and then back up the mounted filesystem.  I think this would be exceedingly slow though.